# Running a script on rtorrent completion

Tags: unix, bittorrent, rtorrent

How can I make rtorrent run a script when it's finished downloading a torrent, with the full path to the torrent's folder as a parameter?

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer:

```
system.method.set_key = event.download.finished,some_name_for_this_command,"execute=/path/to/script.sh,$d.get_name="
```

Comment: Where did you put ? in `.rtorrent.rc` ? I put myself, restarted rtorrent service and it crashes